# unable to import sample Data into Apache atlas

Tags: apache-atlas

I have installed Apache atlas using docker with the help of the below URL 
https://github.com/michalmiklas/atlas-docker

Now while importing sample data into to apache atlas using the below command,

```
bash-4.4# ./apache-atlas/bin/quick_start.py  http://localhost:21000/
```

it is throwing the below error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.atlas.AtlasServiceException: Metadata service API org.apache.atlas.AtlasClientV2$API_V2@30f842ca failed with status 403 (Forbidden) Response Body ({"errorCode":"ATLAS-403-00-001","errorMessage":"bird is not authorized to perform create classification-def Dimension"})
        at org.apache.atlas.AtlasBaseClient.callAPIWithResource(AtlasBaseClient.java:395)
        at org.apache.atlas.AtlasBaseClient.callAPIWithResource(AtlasBaseClient.java:323)
        at org.apache.atlas.AtlasBaseClient.callAPI(AtlasBaseClient.java:211)
        at org.apache.atlas.AtlasClientV2.createAtlasTypeDefs(AtlasClientV2.java:227)
        at org.apache.atlas.examples.QuickStartV2.createTypes(QuickStartV2.java:185)
        at org.apache.atlas.examples.QuickStartV2.runQuickstart(QuickStartV2.java:141)
        at org.apache.atlas.examples.QuickStartV2.main(QuickStartV2.java:126)
No sample data added to Apache Atlas Server.
```

below is the total log for your reference.

```
 ./bin/apache-atlas/bin/quick_start.py  http://localhost:21000/
log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.
log4j:WARN No such property [maxBackupIndex] in org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.
log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.
log4j:WARN No such property [maxBackupIndex] in org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.
log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.
Enter username for atlas :- bird
Enter password for atlas :-

Creating sample types:
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.atlas.AtlasServiceException: Metadata service API org.apache.atlas.AtlasClientV2$API_V2@30f842ca failed with status 403 (Forbidden) Response Body ({"errorCode":"ATLAS-403-00-001","errorMessage":"bird is not authorized to perform create classification-def Dimension"})
        at org.apache.atlas.AtlasBaseClient.callAPIWithResource(AtlasBaseClient.java:395)
        at org.apache.atlas.AtlasBaseClient.callAPIWithResource(AtlasBaseClient.java:323)
        at org.apache.atlas.AtlasBaseClient.callAPI(AtlasBaseClient.java:211)
        at org.apache.atlas.AtlasClientV2.createAtlasTypeDefs(AtlasClientV2.java:227)
        at org.apache.atlas.examples.QuickStartV2.createTypes(QuickStartV2.java:185)
        at org.apache.atlas.examples.QuickStartV2.runQuickstart(QuickStartV2.java:141)
        at org.apache.atlas.examples.QuickStartV2.main(QuickStartV2.java:126)
No sample data added to Apache Atlas Server.
```

JFI, **bird** is admin user group user and i have also tried with **DATA_STEWARD** and **DATA_SCIENTIST** user groups but the result is same.

Answer (score 2):

The user has to use the existing username and password to import Data into APACHE-ATLAS.

**Default Username** : admin (case sensitive)

**Password** : admin

Once you install the Apache Atlas, first check the Zookeeper server status and do not change the any user configurations.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I am using admin and admin as credentials but still facing the same error. Any help ?